# Convert from float to length

Tags: pstricks, lengths

I am using `\pst@divide` to divide a length in half

```
\setlength{\RLEN}{4cm}
\addlength{\RLEN}{\OFFSET}
\pst@divide{\RLEN}{2cm}\RLEN
...
\setlength{\DIST}{2cm}
\addlength{\DIST}{\RLEN} % does not work.
```

the problem is that `\pst@divide` returns a float and I need it to be a length because later I add another length to the result using `\addlength`. Any suggestion how to covert from a float to a length or maybe how to add two float values.

Comment: "does not work" does not work for me. Please post the actual error message. Normally you simply need to add a unit (`pt`) if non is included.

Comment: "does not work" means that it has the value 0

Comment: That's the problem with "does not work". It can man 1.000 different things.

Comment: Sorry, I shall keep that in mind next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the etex extension `\dimexpr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\RLEN
\newlength\DIST
\newlength\OFFSET \OFFSET=1cm
\begin{document}

\setlength\RLEN{\dimexpr4cm+\OFFSET\relax}
\setlength\RLEN{0.5\RLEN}
\the\RLEN

\setlength\DIST{\dimexpr2cm+\RLEN\relax}
\the\DIST

\end{document}
```

However, you can always use `\addtolength\DIST{\XX pt}` if `\XX` is not a length

Comment: Thanks! That's a much more simpler way for me to do these distance calculations :)